# Setting HTTP headers with JSONRequest in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, http-headers

I want to set the http headers for a request using the JSONRequest object in Javascript.
Also, if somebody can tell about the availability of JSONRequest object in all modern browsers.

Comment: The available is pretty much zero. Don't expect any browser to support it. I don't even think it's a standard yet.

Comment: Being able to set custom headers would pretty much defeat the point, no?

Comment: @ThiefMaster I really doubt it will ever become a standard :P

Comment: Since JSONRequest object is not a standard, its not yet implemented by the browser.
To read further on the same, visit [JSON Request Sender](http://www.json.org/JSONRequest.html)

Comment: @melpomene: my project uses both xml and json requests because of different data sources, I need to set the headers for each request.

Comment: So you couldn't use `JSONRequest` even if it existed.

Comment: @melpomene: Consider I'm only using the JSONRequest, then how do we set the http headers?

Comment: 1. You can't use `JSONRequest` because it doesn't exist. 2. If it did exist, it wouldn't let you set HTTP headers. What part of this is unclear?

Comment: @melpomene: 
>>Being able to set custom headers would pretty much defeat the point, no? 
What makes you say that?